# Assign shapes to the points of n-1 of your n lines with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot 3 lines in one graph and, for two of those lines, use shapes to mark the points that determine the lines. I do not manage to do this without losing control of the shapes. Is there a way to not use shapes marking the points for one line without losing control on setting the shape of the points of the other lines?

Consider the following example:

```
years = 2001:2005
A = c(2, 3, 2.5, 2, 2.2)
B = c(2, 2.3, 2.8, 2, 3.2)
C = rep(2.1, 5)
DT = data.table(years, A, B, C)
mDT = melt(DT, id.vars = 'years', value.name = "Value", variable.name = "Parameter")
```

I want to represent this data visually through line graphs and points. For parameters A and B I want the points to have a shape. For C I do not want them to have a shape. With `ggplot` I tried:

```
ggplot(mDT, aes(x = years, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Parameter, colour = Parameter)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "twodash", "dotted")) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Parameter)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("A" = 4, "B" = 6, "C" = ""))
```

But then the shapes for A and B are 4s and 6s. This also doesn't work because then I have not enough values

```
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(4, 6))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
scale_shape_manual(values = c("A" = 4, "B" = 6, "C" = ""))
```

it coerces all the values in the vector to characters since vectors can only hold values of the same data type. Instead use

```
scale_shape_manual(values = c("A" = 4, "B" = 6, "C" = NA))
```

Where the `NA` won't change the fact the all the other values are numeric.